# Scratching a paragraph, or a specified amount of text in latex

Tags: environments, paragraphs

I want to figure out how to scratch(draw an oblique or diagonal line across the text) out some number of lines(in particular, a paragraph). Does anyone know of a simple command to do this? I am expecting that something as simple as \begin{comment} and \end{comment} command that just hides a given amount of text exists.

I would appreciate any amount of help.

Comment: There is the `comment` package, which provides the `comment` environment.  But then, everything between `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` doesn't appear at all in the output (somewhat like comments in a coding language).

Comment: There is also the censor package, but it redacts everything.

Comment: If it can be a horizontal scratch, take a look to the `changes` package. In short, you can use `foo  \deleted{foo} baz` to see "bar"  strike-through and use the `final` option to see just "foo baz". You can include several lines of text in this command but only one paragraph. Allows page breaks.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `tikzmark`. Note, this will not work across page breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}

\newenvironment{scratch}{\pgfmark{A}}{\pgfmark{B}\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{\draw[thick] let \p1=(pic cs:A), \p2=(pic cs:B) in (\x1,\y2)--([shift={(\linewidth,-1ex)}]\x1,\y1);}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{scratch}
\lipsum[2]
\end{scratch}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use the tikzpagenodes package to locate `-| (current page text area.east)` and `-| (current page text area.west)` .See also `\iftikzmarkoncurrentpage`

Answer (score 2):

Another idea would be to use the `tcolorbox` package which would allow the paragraphs with the scratch mark to break over pages (but there might be problems if you want to use this inside other boxes or tables for examples):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable, skins}

\NewTColorBox{scratch}{ }{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    size=minimal,
    colback=transparent!0,
    colframe=transparent!0,
    overlay={
        \draw (frame.south west)
            -- (frame.north east);
    }
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{scratch}
\lipsum[2]
\end{scratch}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{scratch}
\lipsum[5-7]
\end{scratch}

\end{document}
```

[image]